# JUnit makes a new instance of the class without @BeforeEach?

Tags: java, testing, junit

In order to refactor testing, we are taught that JUnit will make a new instance of the class every time by doing the following:

```
public class someClassTest{

  final private someClass obj1 = new someClass();

  @Test
  public void t1() {
      Assertions.assertEquals(1, obj1.returnOne());
  }

  @Test
  public void t2() {
      Assertions.assertEquals(8, obj1.return(2));
  }
}
```

Rather than using something like

```
@BeforeEach
void setup(){
someClass obj1 = new someClass();}
```

or initializing it inside the test methods every time.

My question is, why and how does my first block of code work to achieve the same purpose as the @BeforeEach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit framework manages that. It creates a new instance of the test class (`someClassTest`) before each test.

Take a look at this example:

```
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }
}
```

Run it and you'll see that the test class instance is different in `test1` and `test2`, for example:

```
SampleTest@4e515669
SampleTest@504bae78
```

From that point is just an ordinary behavior of Java. 
If you have a field in an object, it will be re-created (and re-initialized):

```
public class SampleTest {
   private int i = 0;

   @Test
   public void test1() {
      // i is 0, so lets increase and see what happens in test2
      i++;
   }
   @Test
   public void test2() {
     // here i is again 0 because it was re-created, we have a different object of SampleTest 

   }
}
```